# Difference between the dot operator and a get method

Tags: c++

I have a vector class

```
class Vector {
public:
    double x, y, z;
    Vector add(Vector v) {
        return Vector(x+v.x, y+v.y, z+v.z);
    }
};
```

and I have a class Ray

```
class Ray {
public:
    Vector origin, direction;
    Vector getOrigin() { return origin; }
};
```

In some method, I do:

```
Vector x = ray.origin().add(normal); // doesn't work
Vector y = ray.getRayOrigin().add(normal); // works
```

error message: Type vector doesn't provide a call operator

Why can't I just access the vector directly?

Comment: `origin()` isnt a function in your class, is it? I believe saying `.origin` instead of `.origin()` would work.

Comment: I think you should change the title, you're not asking for the *Difference between the dot operator and a get method*

Comment: @AymanKhamouma OP thought they were asking this, they obviously didn't realize their problem otherwise they wouldn't have posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `origin` is not a function. Remove the parentheses when you access it.

Comment: okay I'm dumb .... another question, is there any other different between doing ray.origin and ray.getOrigin() ?

Comment: @nevermind `getOrigin()` returns a copy, so changes made to it will not affect `origin`

Answer (score 2):

Xīcò has the correct solution, but not the right symptom.

`origin` doesn't have to be a function. The `Vector` class could overload `operator()` and be called as if it were a function, and that's the message the compiler is trying to get across.

`ray.origin` allows anyone to do anything to `ray`'s `origin` member including things that could be harmful to `ray`. Very uncool. The purpose of setters and getters is to regulate access to member variables. The goal is self defence.

OP's `getOrigin` method doesn't return origin. It returns a copy of origin. A malicious cretin can do anything they want to the copy without breaking `ray`. This is most often the *right way* unless the object returned is intended to be modified or prohibitively expensive to copy. In that modification case, lock down the returned object with private data, and getters and setters of it's own. In the expensive copy case, declare the return value to be `const` to reduce the possibility of damage.

A good setter will vet all input to the `origin` member before allowing the change to take place. If the caller tries to feed in values that are inconsistent with `origin`, `ray` can slap it down.

Directly accessing `origin` through `.` allows `ray` no defence whatsoever. It also prevents `ray` from changing the implementation of origin without also chancing origin's users.

Whether these are concerns with a pair of simple classes like `Vector` and `Ray`, is a matter of coding style and necessity, but locking down data access to the minimum necessary is generally a good habit to get into and a must when developing complicated software.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Vector {
  public:
    double x, y, z;
    Vector add(Vector v) {
      return Vector(x+v.x, y+v.y, z+v.z);
    }
};

class Ray {
  public:
    Vector origin, direction;
    Vector getOrigin() { return origin; }
    Vector& getOrigin2() { return origin; }
};

int main() {
    Ray ray;
    Vector v1 = ray.origin;  // returns origin member
    Vector v2 = ray.getOrigin(); // returns a copy of origin member
    Vector v3 = ray.getOrigin2(); // same as v1, returns origin member
}
```